# Proving that a random permutation generator is not fair

Tags: co.combinatorics, randomized-algorithms

If I'm generating random permutations using the following algorithm:

```
start with p = identity permutation.
at each iteration, 
pick two random numbers i,j from {1,2... n}
swap p(i) with p(j). 
repeat m times, and m is large as you wish.
```

My guess is that this method is not fair. Namely, not all permutations are chosen with probability of 1/n!.

Because for simpler permutations, there is greater room for choice, 
but I just cannot prove it

Any idea? 
thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If $m$ is fixed while $n$ grows to infinity, then it's easy to see this algorithm doesn't produce a uniformly random permutation: it produces a permutation whose [bubble-sort distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_tau_distance) from the identity is at most $m$, while a random permutation has expected distance $\frac{n}{2}$ from the identity.

*However*, when $m$ is allowed to grow with $n$, this algorithm samples from a distribution on permutations which quickly gets very close to uniform. Indeed, this algorithm takes $m$ steps from a natural reversible Markov chain on the symmetric group whose stationary distribution is the uniform distribution. A classical result of [Diaconis and Shahshahani](https://statistics.stanford.edu/sites/default/files/EFS%20NSF%20149.pdf) shows that the [total variation distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation_distance_of_probability_measures) between the distribution $\mathbb{P}_m$ on the permutation output by the algorithm after $m$ steps, and the uniform distribution $\mathbb{P}_U$ is

$$
2\left(\frac1e - e^{-e^{-2c}}\right) + o(1) \le \frac12 \|\mathbb{P}_m - \mathbb{P}_Y\|_1 \lesssim e^{-2c},
$$

where

$$
c = \frac{m - \frac12 n\log n}{n}.
$$